# Why is Apache 2.4 permanent redirecting (301) this to non www?

Tags: apache, http-redirect

Why is Apache 2.4 permanent redirecting (301) this to non www?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.net
    ServerAlias www.domain.com www.domain.org
    Include conf/extra/domain/httpd-vhosts.domain.http
</VirtualHost>
```

The include file has the ordinary DocumentRoot, Directory, etc.  But no redirect or rewrite conditions/rules.
.htaccess has some rewrite conditions/rules but nothing re: www.  And no 301's.

Browser cache cleared and viewing with HttpWatch can see the non cached redirect from server on first use.  Subsequent use the redirect is from cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.  Found it buried in an earlier loading global conf.
Good thing I posted about it here or I probably never would have found it. ;)